# Set Checkbox Pressed Background Color Windows Phone 8 in C#

Tags: checkbox, windows-phone-8, themes

How can I universally set the color of a checkbox/radiobutton throughout my app?

I am able to change the accent color like so

```
            (App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 162, 0, 37);
```

But it is not applied to the checkboxes, radiobuttons, when pressed.
I tried

```
            App.Current.Resources["CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush"] = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 162, 0, 37);

            App.Current.Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedColor"] = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 162, 0, 37);
```

Both these return a not implemented exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Isolated Settings

```
Application.Current.IsolatedSetings.Add("YOur Key",System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 162, 0, 37).ToString())
```

AND USE WHEN NEEDED

VIA

```
var color = Application.Current.IsolatedSetings["Your Key"]
```

Comment: not my own key, I am looking for the key for checkbox when pressed color. none of the ones i provided above from the msdn website work.

Comment: you cannot change that system color, but you can define your own style

Answer (score 2):

- You can change color of `SolidColorBrush` in code

  ```
  (App.Current.Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255,
  ```

  162, 0, 37);

  ```
  (App.Current.Resources["PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255,
  ```

  162, 0, 37);
- you can also make implicit style and put it in App.xaml resources and
  it will be applied to all instances of this control (except when you
  refer in some control to explicit style)

  For example: Right Click on RadioButton  Edit template Edit a copy
  choose Define in Application choose Apply to all

  Change colors based on your scenario.